# Does VS2015 Update 1 include VS2015?

Tags: visual-studio-2015, updates

Does anyone know whether [VS2015 Community Update 1](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=49989) includes VS2015 Community i.e. the main product itself? The huge file size (3.7GB) suggests that it should, but I want to confirm that before downloading the huge thing on a metered connection. The download page doesn't mention it anywhere.

Or do I need to download VS2015 separately and then download this one on top of that?

**Update**: I later found that the link I posted above is not correct (doesn't refer to Community edition). The one in the accepted answer is the correct one.

Comment: I downloaded iso file with 3.7 GB recently. I found VS2015 community edition inside and working smoothly.

Comment: @Midhun: Thx a bunch. For close-voters, does a question need to contain actual code to be called on-topic? I find VS2015 VERY programming-related and I believe this question can help quite a few programmers out there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. From [Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2015 with Update 1](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=49988) (**highlight** mine):

> Note: If you have installed Visual Studio Community 2015 (original release version) and run this download from this page, only Update 1 is installed. **If you haven't installed Visual Studio Community 2015 and run the download, both Visual Studio Community 2015 and Update 1 are installed.** In either instance, Visual Studio 2015 Language Packs (original release versions) can also be installed.

Comment: mmm... Thanks a lot. That makes things a bit muddy though. The link u have posted is slightly different than the one in my post. Both pages claim to be VS2015 Community Update 1, but mine is sized at 3.7GB, whereas yours is over 5GB. :S

Comment: Got it. The link I have posted is not Community Edition. Yours is the correct one. Thanks again.

Comment: While we're at it, does there exist a separate download of Update 1 that would not contain the entire VS2015 Community, but just the updates and therefore would hopefully be of much smaller size?